# Has Anyone Else's Scenekit App Slowed and Started Stuttering since iOS 12

Tags: performance, scenekit, metal, xcode10, ios12

Scenekit app was working as desired until devices upgraded to iOS 12.  Setting target iOS to 11.4.1 or 12 delivers same unacceptable results on devices now that iOS 12 is installed.

Framerate dropped to near 40 from 60 just by installing iOS 12 on devices.

Note that changing Rendering API to OpenGL from default or Metal produces better frame rate and less stuttering but I'm looking to keep metal as the Rendering API.

App running on iOS 11.4.1 device:

[image: iOS 11.4.1]

App running on iOS 12 device:

[image: iOS 12]